# Font not showing on wordpress theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fonts

I duplicated/cloned my wordpress template theme so I can test out a new font on it.  My new font is not showing up though. On the new test theme I removed all the current .woff font files and uploaded my new font .woff files. So I don't believe this is a file type issue?  From there, I updated the font-family on the html & body.  I did not create any new folders within the 'fonts' folder so the url should not be wrong either. Also there was nothing in the includes.php file for me to change font-wise either.

I will supply you my current working wordpress @font-face file where the fonts are correctly displaying below and underneath that I will show you my new test @font-face file.

LAST NOTE: When I go to the direct link for the font file, it works and downloads it: https://site/wp-content/themes/(new theme)/fonts/Metropolis-Regular.woff

Fonts that are displaying correctly on current theme:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gotham Book';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Gotham Book'), url('../fonts/GothamBook.woff') format('woff');
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gotham Book Italic';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Gotham Book Italic'), url('../fonts/GothamBookItalic.woff') format('woff');
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gotham Light';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Gotham Light'), url('../fonts/GothamLight.woff') format('woff');
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gotham Light Italic';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Gotham Light Italic'), url('../fonts/GothamLightItalic.woff') format('woff');
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gotham Medium';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Gotham Medium'), url('../fonts/GothamMedium.woff') format('woff');
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gotham Medium';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Gotham Medium'), url('../fonts/GothamMedium_1.woff') format('woff');
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gotham Medium Italic';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Gotham Medium Italic'), url('../fonts/GothamMediumItalic.woff') format('woff');
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gotham Bold';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Gotham Bold'), url('../fonts/GothamBold.woff') format('woff');
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gotham Bold';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Gotham Bold'), url('../fonts/Gotham-Bold.woff') format('woff');
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gotham Bold Italic';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Gotham Bold Italic'), url('../fonts/GothamBoldItalic.woff') format('woff');
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gotham Black Regular';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Gotham Black Regular'), url('../fonts/Gotham-Black.woff') format('woff');
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gotham Light Regular';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Gotham Light Regular'), url('../fonts/Gotham-Light.woff') format('woff');
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gotham Thin Regular';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Gotham Thin Regular'), url('../fonts/Gotham-Thin.woff') format('woff');
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gotham XLight Regular';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Gotham XLight Regular'), url('../fonts/Gotham-XLight.woff') format('woff');
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gotham Book Italic';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Gotham Book Italic'), url('../fonts/Gotham-BookItalic.woff') format('woff');
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gotham Thin Italic';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Gotham Thin Italic'), url('../fonts/Gotham-ThinItalic.woff') format('woff');
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gotham Ultra Italic';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Gotham Ultra Italic'), url('../fonts/Gotham-UltraItalic.woff') format('woff');
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gotham XLight Italic';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Gotham XLight Italic'), url('../fonts/Gotham-XLightItalic.woff') format('woff');
}
```

New Test fonts that are not displaying.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Metropolis Black';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Metropolis Black'), url('../fonts/Metropolis-Black.woff') format('woff');
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Metropolis Black Italic';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Metropolis Black Italic'), url('../fonts/Metropolis-BlackItalic.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Metropolis Bold';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Metropolis Bold'), url('../fonts/Metropolis-Bold.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Metropolis Bold Italic';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Metropolis Bold Italic'), url('../fonts/Metropolis-BoldItalic.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Metropolis Extra Bold';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Metropolis Extra Bold'), url('../fonts/Metropolis-ExtraBold.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Metropolis Extra Bold Italic';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Metropolis Extra Bold Italic'), url('../fonts/Metropolis-ExtraBoldItalic.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Metropolis Extra Light';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Metropolis Extra Light'), url('../fonts/Metropolis-ExtraLight.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Metropolis Extra Light Italic';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Metropolis Extra Light Italic'), url('../fonts/Metropolis-ExtraLightItalic.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Metropolis Light';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Metropolis Light'), url('../fonts/Metropolis-Light.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Metropolis Light Italic';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Metropolis Light Italic'), url('../fonts/Metropolis-LightItalic.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Metropolis Medium';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Metropolis Medium'), url('../fonts/Metropolis-Medium.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Metropolis Medium Italic';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Metropolis Medium Italic'), url('../fonts/Metropolis-MediumItalic.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Metropolis Regular';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Metropolis Regular'), url('../fonts/Metropolis-Regular.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Metropolis Regular Italic';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Metropolis Regular Italic'), url('../fonts/Metropolis-RegularItalic.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Metropolis Semi Bold';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Metropolis Semi Bold'), url('../fonts/Metropolis-SemiBold.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Metropolis Semi Bold Italic';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Metropolis Semi Bold Italic'), url('../fonts/Metropolis-SemiBoldItalic.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Metropolis Thin';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Metropolis Thin'), url('../fonts/Metropolis-Thin.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Metropolis Thin Italic';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Metropolis Thin Italic'), url('../fonts/Metropolis-ThinItalic.woff') format('woff');
}
```

Current working theme html, body font-family:

```
html, body {
    font-family:"Gotham A", "Gotham B", Helvetica, Arial;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-weight:$medium;
    color:$color-text;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

New test theme html, body font-family not working:

```
html, body {
    font-family: 'Metropolis Regular', Helvetica, Arial;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-weight:$medium;
    color:$color-text;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Does your browser inspector show any console errors related to loading of the fonts?

Comment: 3 errors, but nothing font related.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) arrow.svg:1


Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
connect.facebook.net


Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')

Comment: To check if the font files themselves are working, try creating a simple HTML file on your computer in the same folder as your font files, which loads the font files and uses them to style some text.

Comment: Yes, they are working this way.

Comment: If I put this in my customize css section on wordpress it also works.

@font-face {
 font-family:'Metropolis Regular';
 src:url(
https://(site)/wp-content/themes/(test-theme)/fonts/Metropolis-Regular.woff)
}